# app-indexed-db cann't validate session error

Tags: polymer, indexeddb

I'm using Polymer Element app-indexeddb-mirror for simple testing , its failing with an error "cannot validate session". I have did force cache clear on browser and still having the same issue. Any help would be greatly apreciated ! Thank you !

```html
<app-indexeddb-mirror log id="idb" data="{{item}}" worker-url="{{workerUrl}}" key="sale" persisted-data="{{persistedItem}}" online="[[online]]">
    </app-indexeddb-mirror>

    <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{persistedItem}}" as="item">
      <div>[[item.name]]</div>
    </template>
  </template>
```

```html
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'validateSession' of undefined
    at HTMLElement.<anonymous> (app-indexeddb-mirror.html:249)
    at HTMLElement._enqueueTransaction (app-storage-behavior.html:332)
    at HTMLElement.__updatePersistedData (app-indexeddb-mirror.html:248)
    at HTMLElement._complexObserverEffect (polymer.html:1672)
    at HTMLElement._effectEffects (polymer.html:1507)
    at HTMLElement._propertySetter (polymer.html:1491)
    at HTMLElement.__setProperty (polymer.html:1500)
    at HTMLElement._applyConfig (polymer.html:2111)
    at HTMLElement._afterClientsReady (polymer.html:2105)
    at HTMLElement._ready (polymer-mini.html:70)
```

Comment: Any solution for this? I'm having the same issue

Comment: By the way the error is caused because client is unkown not that it can't validate session.